# Python pytest: local variable 'length' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I am not sure what is wrong in the following code snippet.

I have the following two versions of a function.

**Version 1**

```
def _check_array_lengths(self, data):
    for i, values in data.items():
        if i == 0:
            length = len(values)
        if length != len(values):
            raise ValueError('All values must be the same length')
```

When I run test, the above function fails with a msg
"ERROR tests/test_dataframe.py - UnboundLocalError: **local variable 'length' referenced before assignment**"

**Version 2**

```
def _check_array_lengths(self, data):
    for i, values in enumerate(data.values()):
        if i == 0:
            length = len(values)
        if length != len(values):
            raise ValueError('All values must be the same length')
```

The test for this function works fine and I wonder why I don't see the same error msg(mentioned above) here. How that "enumerate" is causing this change in behavior!

May be something really silly but I couldn't figure it out yet.

Here is my test function

```
def test_array_length(self):
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        pdc.DataFrame({'a': np.array([1, 2]), 
                       'b': np.array([1])})
```

can you please help ?

Comment: If `i` is not `0` then `length` has no value to compare against `len(values)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second version, the first value of `i` is guaranteed to be `0`. So the condition `if i == 0:` will be true, and `length` will be set. Then the comparison `if length != len(values):` will be able to use the `length` variable.

In the first version is `i` iterates over the dataframe indexes, not a numeric sequence. The values of `i` will be `'a'` and `'b'`. The `if i == 0:` condition will never be true, so you never set `length`, and get an error when you try to compare it.